# Reset button to a count and switching tabs android studio

Tags: java, android, count

I am making this beer/drink app as a fun project. I checked around the site and couldn't find anything specific to my problem. I would greatly appreciate help at two things;

I would like a button to reset whatever the count gets to in this code, I can't seem to figure out what I need..

The countButton is for beer and the drinkButton is for, well yeah, drinks.

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

// Private member field to keep track of the count
private int mCount = 0;
private int mSum = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);


    final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
    final TextView sumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSum);
    final ImageButton countButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.beerCount);
    final ImageButton drinkButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.drinkCount);


    countButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCount++;
            mSum += 72;
            countTextView.setText("You have been drinking " + mCount + " units!");
            sumTextView.setText("Sum:" + mSum + "!");
        }
    });

    drinkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCount++;
            mSum += 96;
            countTextView.setText("You have been drinking " + mCount + " units!");
            sumTextView.setText("Sum:" + mSum + "!");
        }
    });
```

Also, the count does remove itself when I toggle through tabs in the app, any ideas to make it stay, and only removing by the reset button?

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: do you need to reset mCount or mSum?

Comment: I need to reset mSum

Comment: and mSum is declared where?

Comment: finally, you need a button  to reset that?

Comment: yeah thats the idea, to reset whatever the count gets to when i press the count buttons

Comment: you are incrementing mSum in your count button. Instead of  the whole thing you want to reset it? Your question is unclear to me. If you want to reset mSum there, simply put the line mSum = 0 at the  beginning.

Comment: When i press the buttons, one for beer, one for drinks, it adds a count. I want a button that can clear that count.

Answer (score 0):

For what you require, simply add a third button to your activity and in its onCLickListener, set the values to 0.

Something like this.

```
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.mSum = 0;
    }
});
```